# Is $\frac{b^2 - 1}{\sigma(b^2) - b^2} + 1$ always an odd prime for odd composite $b$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, conjectures, mathematica, divisor-sum

Let $\sigma(x)$ be the sum of the divisors of $x$.

Here is my *original question*:

> If $\bigg(\sigma(b^2) - b^2\bigg) \mid \bigg(b^2 - 1\bigg)$, is $$\frac{b^2 - 1}{\sigma(b^2) - b^2} + 1$$ always an odd prime for $b$ odd?

Preliminary computations using Mathematica show that this must be true.  Is it?

**Added March 18 2017**

When $b = p^k$ where $p$ is an odd prime and $k \geq 1$, we have
$$\frac{b^2 - 1}{\sigma(b^2) - b^2} + 1 = \frac{\sigma(b^2) - 1}{\sigma(b^2) - b^2} = \frac{\sigma(p^{2k}) - 1}{\sigma(p^{2k}) - p^{2k}} = \frac{p\sigma(p^{2k-1})}{\sigma(p^{2k-1})} = p,$$
validating [didgogns](https://math.stackexchange.com/u/392996)'s claim in the comments.  Hence, I modify my original question slightly as follows:

**MODIFIED QUESTION**

> If $\bigg(\sigma(b^2) - b^2\bigg) \mid \bigg(b^2 - 1\bigg)$, is $$\frac{b^2 - 1}{\sigma(b^2) - b^2} + 1$$ always an odd prime for $b$ an odd composite?

Comment: If the downvoter could just explain his/her vote, I would consider it as constructive feedback.

Comment: Is there any non prime or prime-power solutions for $b$? For prime or prime power $b$, this is quite trivial.

Comment: Thanks @didgogns!  I have validated your claim, and included some additional notes in my question, including a modification of my original inquiry towards the end.

Comment: How far have you computed?

Comment: @KonstantinosGaitanas, we have used Mathematica and determined that $b > {10}^{10}$.  Elsewhere (in another one of my MSE posts), Charles computed until $b < {10}^{11}$ and found no examples.